# Two local branches track separate remote Git repos

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have one local repo with two branches

- master
- private

I want the master branch to track origin/master from the **public** repo on Github. I want the private branch to track origin_private/master from the **private** repo on Github.

Assuming this is a good idea/good setup, I have run into problems trying to make those two branches track separate remote repos.

For example, see this command history; I have annotated it with my own remarks:

```
C:\Users\denman\WebstormProjects\suman>git branch
* master
  private

C:\Users\denman\WebstormProjects\suman>git branch -u origin/master master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin. (cool thanks Git)

C:\Users\denman\WebstormProjects\suman>git checkout private
Switched to branch 'private'

C:\Users\denman\WebstormProjects\suman>git branch -u origin_private/master master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin_private.
(cool thanks Git)

C:\Users\denman\WebstormProjects\suman>git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch. (not cool Git!)
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> private
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I issued the standard call to track a remote branch using the "git branch -u" command but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

You first setup `master` to track `origin/master`, then you setup again `master` to track `private_origin/master`. In your second track command the last argument should be `private`. Actually as you have `private` checked out, you can leave out the last argument, our you can spare the checkout if you just want to set the tracking branch.

Comment: You may also want to fofllow the [convention](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/forking-workflow) where the public repo is named "upstream" and your private repo is named "origin".  It's a common setup for a "forking" workflow.

Comment: @tgharold well, while I agree and also use this convention, there are also other conventions like having the upstream called `master` and having all other remotes including your own named like the forking user. After all this is just private setup that noone else will ever see except in a SO question, so it doesn't matter much how he calls his remotes. ;-)